# downloading and installing package from github

Tags: r, github

Does anyone know how to install the package available at https://github.com/Zhangxf-ccnu/DiffGraph?
It would be a great help if someone could share a few lines of codes.
Here is my try.

```
library(devtools)
ulr = "https://github.com/Zhangxf-ccnu/DiffGraph"
download.packages(pkgs = "DiffGraph",destdir = getwd(),
                   repos = ulr, type = "source",
                   method =  "internal")
```

The warning is:

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://github.com/Zhangxf-ccnu/DiffGraph/src/contrib:
  scheme not supported in URL 'https://github.com/Zhangxf-ccnu/DiffGraph/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in download.packages(pkgs = "DiffGraph", destdir = getwd(), repos = ulr,  :
  no package ‘DiffGraph’ at the repositories
     [,1] [,2]
```

Best,
Amare

Comment: Did you try the instructions given in the readme?
```Install the DiffGraph pacakge:
Download the package source from https://github.com/Zhangxf-ccnu/DiffGraph 
and then install the package using the following command:
install.packages("path/DiffGraph_1.1.1.tar.gz", type = "source")
where "path" is the path where the "DiffGraph_1.1.1.tar.gz" is located.```

Comment: Have you installed devtools (```install.packages("devtools")``` and loaded that first?  You need to do so first in order to install packages from github and also run ```devtools::install_github("r-lib/devtools")``` before you run your line above to install DiffGraph.